# PWA on Heroku- Redirecting HTTP Traffic To HTTPS

Tags: heroku, progressive-web-apps

I am working on `Progressive Web App` in `React` and I set up the website on `Heroku`. When I tests that with `Lighthouse` I got the warning:

Does not tredirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS

Based on docs:

Lighthouse changes the page's URL to http, loads the page, and then waits for the event from the Chrome Debugger that indicates that the page is secure.

And indeed I can access the website using https or http. Is there a way to redirect that on Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. As I am using `React`the solution was simple. I created a file `static.json` in main folder and added `"https_only": true` there. It "forces" https for all requests. See [this section](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#https-only) of the buildpack docs.

Comment: Yes, thanks. To be clear, the static.json file must be at the root of the developping project's folder (with the package.json), not the root of the build.